# Rendering webview inside listview have annoying behaviour

Tags: android, listview, webview

I have a strange problem using webview inside listview

the webview sometimes work probably and sometimes not showing anything it just render an empty webview

whan I add a fixed height to webview it works fine, but I need to keep the height with wrap content as I can't define the height of the content

can any one suggest me any solution please

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case I was rendering the WebView inside a LinearLayout in my ListView row. Removing the parent LinearLayout solved the issue.